# XmlDocument.Save() with exception System.ObjectDisposedException: Cannot access a closed file

Tags: c#, .net

I am using XmlDocument API to save my current project state after some changes.

Sometimes I get an exception when I call XmlDocuemt.Save().

After throwing the exception, my xml file content size goes to 0KB (All the data is deleted).

I have used an object based lock for thread safe.

```
private static object syncFileReadWrite = new object();

lock (syncFileReadWrite)
            {
                try
                {
                    XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
                    doc.Load("test.xml");
                    XmlNodeList NodeList = doc.SelectNodes("/Test/");
                    foreach (XmlNode nodeName in NodeList)
                    {
                        String Source = nodeName.Attributes["SOURCE"].Value.ToString();
                        if (Source.Equals(path))
                        {
                            nodeName.Attributes["TIME"].Value = recentEventTime;                          
                        }                
                    }
                    doc.Save("test.xml");
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
                }
            }
```

I am getting below exception while calling doc.Save("test.xml") method.

```
System.ObjectDisposedException: Cannot access a closed file.
   at System.IO.__Error.FileNotOpen()
   at System.IO.FileStream.Flush(Boolean flushToDisk)
   at System.IO.StreamWriter.Flush(Boolean flushStream, Boolean flushEncoder)
   at System.IO.StreamWriter.Dispose(Boolean disposing)
   at System.IO.StreamWriter.Close()
   at System.Xml.XmlTextWriter.Close()
   at System.Xml.XmlDocument.Save(String filename)
```

Comment: Are you sure it is the posted code?

Comment: Yes,This is my code

Comment: The only way the exception could occur if another application (or another part of the code) has the file open.

Comment: You will have to try to narrow it down then, comment out bits and pieces, see how that goes. The code in the question looks fine, you would get different exceptions if multiple threads or processes was accessing the file, this looks like a case of sharing the `doc` variable between threads but you have stated that this is your actual code so then it isn't that.

Comment: Post the *actual* exception text, not just part of the call stack. YOu can get that easily with `Exception.ToString()` or simply writing out the exception object. What comes *after* `XmlDocument.Save()`?

Comment: @jdweng If another application accessing my file means i will get exception like this 'System.IO.IOException: The process cannot access the file 'test.xml' because it is being used by another process.'.

Also another part of code not opening my xml file

Comment: @LasseVågsætherKarlsen Yes, its my actual code.For thread safe i am using object based lock.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos this is my actual exception
System.ObjectDisposedException: Cannot access a closed file.
   at System.IO.__Error.FileNotOpen()
   at System.IO.FileStream.Flush(Boolean flushToDisk)
   at System.IO.StreamWriter.Flush(Boolean flushStream, Boolean flushEncoder)
   at System.IO.StreamWriter.Dispose(Boolean disposing)
   at System.IO.StreamWriter.Close()
   at System.Xml.XmlTextWriter.Close()
   at System.Xml.XmlDocument.Save(String filename)
   at XmlAPI.updateXmlFileByCondition() in XmlAPI.cs:line 246

Comment: Windows allows two uses to open the same file at same time.  First will get read/write permission and second will get only read.

Comment: @jdweng But when we save the file after its changes it throws exception.

Comment: Exactly, you are able to open the file as Read-Only but cannot save.

Comment: @jdweng ok,What causes issue while saving my file?

Comment: Because you have READONLY permission since somebody else opened the file before you.

Comment: @But it throws exception like 'System.IO.IOException: The process cannot access the file 'test.xml' because it is being used by another process.'.I already seen that is what i am using object based lock.

Object based lock prevents concurrent accessing of file.